# Errors with intervention\image

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to resize pictures in my laravel 5 project and I need the intervention/image package. So I ran composer update, than composer require intervention/image and I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found
```

...which is very strange because I can see the Intervention package in my vendor folder
At the top of the file I have `use Intervention\Image\Image;`

I've done this 3 or 4 times today and I still have the problem.
How can I make this package work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `'Intervention\\Image\\' => array($vendorDir . '/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image')`, in `autoload_psr4.php` solved the problem.

Take a look at  **[Class 'Intervention\Image\Image Service Provider' not found [solved]](http://pathros.blogspot.com/2014/11/class-interventionimageimage-service.html)**.

Comment: For those who will encounter the same problem, Adding 'Intervention\\Image\\' => array($vendorDir . '/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image'), in autoload_psr4.php solved the problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback i'll update my answer (adding your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your config/app.php:

'providers' array-

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
```

and on 'aliases' further down

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

In your controller you can then put the following:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

You can then make calls to Image:: methods, for example:

```
 Image::make($request->file('image'))->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
```